# Does 1 tea spoon correspond to half table spoon?

Tags: measurements, utensils

I don't have a measuring glass. I just have a tablespoon (15 ml). Can 1 **tea** spoon be considered half of 1 **table** spoon?

Comment: I've found that in most cases a regular old tea spoon (i.e. not an actual measuring spoon, just whatever you use to stir coffee/tea) is pretty close to the correct amount anyway - and if your recipe is giving teaspoon measurements to begin with then you don't need to be very precise.

Comment: @Aaronut We stir the the tea/coffee with table spoons. That's the only spoon we have. And I used to think those spoons to be tea spoons!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One tablespoon is three teaspoons, so no, it can't be considered half a tablespoon because it's one-third instead :)

You can use three teaspoons to measure out one tablespoon, but it might be tricky to measure the other way: as Rumstacio said below, the 1/3 is by volume, and it can be difficult to eyeball the volume of a semi-sphere (1.3 the height of the spoon is not 1/3 the volume because it's wider at the top).

Comment: In other words, the correct answer is 1/3, not 1/2.

Comment: It is 1/3 by volume - it doesn't mean that if you fill the spoon to 1/3 the height you have the correct amount. (This should be obvious, but I know lots of people who call a spoon filled to half the height "half a spoon"). If you don't have any method of measuring it at least once (e.g. fill a syringe with 5 ml of water, see how high the water comes in your tablespoon), this information doesn't help you much with measurements.

Comment: @rumtscho Good point, added a note about that